# Does generate a Script (Schema and data) affects performance on server/database

Tags: sql-server

I want to generate a Script from a production data base including Schema and data using SSMS tools, but I want to know how this will may impact the database performance wile creating the Script.

The database is quite big in objects (tables, stored procedures) and also have a lot of data.

If I create the script will this impact the server/database performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it will impact performance on the server. It has to read all the metadata about all the objects you are scripting. However, the performance in so minimal as it would be difficult to even measure. This of course is assuming you are talking creating scripts for only the objects and not scripting the data. If you are scripting the data the impact would be significantly more because it has to read all the rows in the tables.